# Is it possible to find statistical data on voting, including the reasons for closing posts?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, statistics

I am looking for a help for my research. I am planning to examine the degree of certainty of the specific reason for closure among the questions to be closed on the Stack Overflow. For this purpose, statistical data about the voting process are needed, especially about the designation of the closing reasons. I found the PendingFlags table containing data about the different votes, but it is only a small set of questions, which is not enough for statistical examinations.

Is it possible to find statistical data of the voting details for closed questions, including the exact closing reasons (off topic, unclear, too broad, etc.) for the posts?

Comment: [It is](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats), though you need [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege (i.e 10K unicorn points) to see that page.

Comment: This is the public data that is available: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1414356 for non-deleted questions

Comment: @oguzismail I don't see exact votes for closure. Just the consensus. If user A voted "Needs details or clarity", user B voted "Needs more focus", then user C votes "Needs details or clarity" again, the vote reason from B is "lost" and the consensus is the other two votes. AFAIK, we don't even have that information exposed in SEDE, either - closed questions just have the majority reason chosen shown, we don't have a breakdown of what the exact votes were. We only have the votes before a consensus is reached.

Comment: You are likely going to need more than just the votes – valid reasons for closure can change as questions are edited or commented on. For example, a question might lack debugging details but turn out to be a duplicate once the information is available.

Comment: Or have different valid reasons at the same time depending the angle of the question: unclear and off topic and too broad and opinion based.

Comment: If you want to do proper research, you really need to contact SE, since info on deleted questions is relevant.  You can try taking shortcuts with data available in SEDE and the data dumps, but for any real research project that won't be sufficient.

Comment: @ErikA It may help to link to the contact page... https://stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Doesn't look like PendingFlags has [data on deleted posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1414536) unfortunately.